# Async eachseries within recursive function

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async.js

I have tried the following code snippet:

```
var arrVal = [[1,2],[[2,3],[4,5]],3,4];
var async = require('async');

var recurse = function(arr , callback) {
async.eachSeries(arr, function(eachVal, callback) { 
    if(typeof eachVal == "object") {
        recurse(eachVal);
    }
    else {
        console.log(eachVal);
        callback(null);
    }
}, callback);};

recurse(arrVal);
```

Expected to print all the numbers present in `arrVal` array, but I am getting only 1,2 (Numbers of 0th index of the array).

What I am doing wrong?
Can someone guide with the better way to achieve what I want to get?

**NOTE: I was hoping to do this asynchronously**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is working fine in your code there is no callback in if condition.
if you want an asynchronous way you can use **async.each instead of async.eachSeries [async.each](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#each)**

The difference with **async.eachSeries** is that each iteration will wait for the async operation to complete before starting the next one.

```
  var arrVal = [[1,2],[[2,3],[4,5]],3,4];
  var async = require('async');

  var recurse = function(arr , callback) {
  async.eachSeries(arr, function(eachVal, each_cb) { 
  if(typeof eachVal === "object") {
      recurse(eachVal);
      each_cb()
  }
  else {
      console.log(eachVal);

      each_cb(null);
  }
}, callback);};

recurse(arrVal);
```

Comment: Ah, my bad! Forgot to add the callback.